# ElasticSearch and tire/Rails: use two fields for a single facet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, elasticsearch, tire

Using Elasticsearch with Rails 3 and tire gem.

I have got facets to work on a couple of fields, but I now have a special requirement and not sure it is possible.
I have two fields on my model Project that both store the same values: Country1 and Country2

The user is allowed to store up to two countries for a project. The drop down menus on both are the same. Neither field is required.

What I would like is a single facet that 'merges' the values from Country1 and Country2 and would handle clicking on those facets intelligently (i.e. would find it whether it was in 1 or 2)

Here's my model so far: (note Country1/2 can be multiple words)

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  mapping do
    indexes :id
    indexes :title, :boost => 100
    indexes :subtitle
    indexes :country1, :type => 'string', :index => 'not_analyzed'
    indexes :country2, :type => 'string', :index => 'not_analyzed'
  end
  def self.search(params)
    tire.search(load: true, page: params[:page], per_page: 10) do
    query do
      boolean do
        must { string params[:query], default_operator: "AND" } if params[:query].present?
        must { term :country1, params[:country] } if params[:country].present?
      end
    end
    sort { by :display_type, "desc" }
    facet "country" do
      terms :country1
    end

  end
end
```

Any tips greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This commit https://github.com/karmi/tire/commit/730813f in Tire brings support for aggregating over multiple fields in the "terms" facet.

The interface is:

```
Tire.search('articles-test') do
  query { string 'foo' }
  # Pass fields as an array, not string
  facet('multi') { terms ['bar', 'baz'] }
end
```

Comment: Thanks Karel, love how quickly this evolves

Comment: Is there any way to have tire return more than one term for facets?  For example if I'm using facets for a user model and the facet would return a user_id and a name so that I don't have to go look up the user's name via the database.

Answer (score 0):

according to the elasticsearch docs for the terms facet http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/facets/terms-facet.html this should be possible:

> Multi Fields:
>
> The term facet can be executed against more than one field, returning
>   the aggregation result across those fields. For example:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {  }
    },
    "facets" : {
        "tag" : {
            "terms" : {
                "fields" : ["tag1", "tag2"],
                "size" : 10
            }
        }
    }
}
```

did you try providing an array of fields to the term facet like `terms :country1, :country2` ?

Comment: Thanks, but no...  using "terms :country1, :country2" gives error (undefined method `delete' for :country2:Symbol) and using "terms [:country1, :country2]" shows a blank facet...(no values)

Comment: This seems to work but I need to test it more:  facet('country') { terms fields: [:country1, :country2]}

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work but I need to test it more: facet('country') { terms fields: [:country1, :country2]}